# Hide downloads from download manager android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am implementing a mp3 downloader for android. I am using native DownloadManager service. Obviously, when I download a file, it also shows the downloading(or downloaded) file in the Download Manager app. I want to hide the downloaded file from Downloaded Manager i.e. I don't want the file to be displayed in the download manager list. Is there any way to acheive this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Try `setVisibleInDownloadsUi()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setVisibleInDownloadsUi%28boolean%29) on your `DownloadManager.Request`.

Comment: Is this code for kotlin?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal: I reference a class (`DownloadManager.Request`) and a method on that class (`setVisibleInDownloadsUi()`). These are available to both Java and Kotlin classes to use.