# DownloadManager: prevent listing files in Download app

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager to download a file my app needs to the /Android/data/com.example.myapp folder. After successful download, the file is listed in the Downloads app list, which I don't want. Anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to hide the download from the Download app:

[Hide downloads from download manager android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950597/hide-downloads-from-download-manager-android)